# Node.js : Why can't I output the create value in function()

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory

Blow the code is my function define.

```
function Monster(id, name, terribleness, intelligence){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.terribleness = terribleness;
    this.intelligence = intelligence;
}

Monster.prototype.energy = function(){
    var amount = this.terribleness * 6 + this.intelligence * 4;
    console.log('Generating', amount, 'electrical energy');
}
```

Than, I apply content and assign Monster.prototype to james.*proto*.

```
Monster.apply(james,['1', 'James', 100, 20])
james._proto_ = Monster.prototype;
```

When I run this line,

```
james._proto_.energy()
```

Output:

> "Generating ***NaN*** electrical energy"

why I can't get a create value **680** in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property is `__proto__`, not `_proto_`. But don't use it, not least because it's not officially supported outside of web browsers; it comes from [Annex B](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-additional-ecmascript-features-for-web-browsers) of the spec.

In general, if you want to change the prototype of an object *after* creating it, that suggests you want to revisit how you created it. But it *is* possible, as of ES2015, with `Object.setPrototypeOf`:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(james, Monster.prototype);
```

Again, this is not recommended.

I'd probably do it *before* calling `Monster` on the instance. So:

```js
function Monster(id, name, terribleness, intelligence){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.terribleness = terribleness;
    this.intelligence = intelligence;
}

Monster.prototype.energy = function(){
    var amount = this.terribleness * 6 + this.intelligence * 4;
    console.log('Generating', amount, 'electrical energy');
};

var james = {}; // However it is you create it
Object.setPrototypeOf(james,  Monster.prototype);
Monster.apply(james,['1', 'James', 100, 20]);
james.energy();
```

Then you'd use `energy` on `james`, because it's `james` that has those properties on it:

```
james.energy();
```

But rather than all that, you'd be better off with simply:

```
james = new Monster('1', 'James', 100, 20);
james.energy();
```

```js
function Monster(id, name, terribleness, intelligence){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.terribleness = terribleness;
    this.intelligence = intelligence;
}

Monster.prototype.energy = function(){
    var amount = this.terribleness * 6 + this.intelligence * 4;
    console.log('Generating', amount, 'electrical energy');
};

var james = new Monster('1', 'James', 100, 20);
james.energy();
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. =)

Answer (score 0):

First, with this line...

```
james._proto_.energy()
```

... context (`this`) of `energy` function call points to `james._proto_`. But the latter doesn't have `terribleness` and `intelligence` properties defined AND doesn't have them on its prototype chain. Hence `NaN` as a result (`*` operation converts its operands to `Number`, and `Number(undefined)` is quite non-surprisingly `NaN`).

What you should do instead is calling `energy` on `james` directly, like this:

```
james.energy()
```

... but before this you should set `Monster.prototype` as `james` prototype (referred by `__proto__` - two underscores at both sides, not one). There are many ways to do this, I'd suggest using the following:

```js
function Monster(id, name, terribleness, intelligence){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.terribleness = terribleness;
    this.intelligence = intelligence;
}

Monster.prototype.energy = function(){
    var amount = this.terribleness * 6 + this.intelligence * 4;
    console.log('Generating', amount, 'electrical energy');
}

var james = Object.create(Monster.prototype);
Monster.apply(james, ['1', 'James', 100, 20]);
james.energy();
```

... if you don't want (for some reasons) to simply use `var james = new Monster(...)` construct.

Comment: Thank for your answer too. =)